# Android RecyclerView scroll to programmatically not working

Tags: android

I am trying to programmatically scroll to a position in my `RecyclerView`, this is what I've tried until now nothing worked in my case:

```
        musicList.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(musicList, null, position);

        musicList.scrollToPosition(position);

        mLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(position);

        musicList.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(position);
```

Is there something I missed?

I have a `LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;` defined and set it to `RecyclerView` as this:

```
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    musicList.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

RecyclerView XML:

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/musicList"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/custom_scrollbar_vertical"/>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Did you try with LinearLayoutManager method scrollToPositionWithOffset

```
//position 2 and second param is offset 20
mLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(2, 20);
```

this works for me. Hope to work and for you !

Comment: Actually, this worked for me but I don't understand why I need an offset to to this...

Comment: What is need of having offset??why 20 is given??

Comment: Thanks a lot. This saved my day. I dunno what is wrong with goolge's dev team. Scrolling is one action and it should be one method to perform it, not  7 (4 on layout manager and 3 on RecyclerView)

Answer (score 1):

**Addendum**:
The proposed scroll functions do **not** work correctly in a scenario with a **collapsing** **toolbar** while the toolbar is **expanded**.
It seems that the recycler view has a fixed height, and while the toolbar is expanded, the recycler is moved down, partially out of the screen. As a consequence also the results of the functions *findLast[Completely]VisibleItemPosition()* are too high. Example: The last visible item is told to be #9, but in fact item #7 is the last one that is really on screen.
I finally chose a workaround like this:

```
if (newPos > 2 /* or other number > 0 */)
{
    AppBarLayout l = findViewById(R.id.appbar);
    if (l != null)
    {
        l.setExpanded(false, true);  // collapse the bar, with animation
    }
}
mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(newPos);
```

Any hints for a better solution are appreciated!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: You are right, in fact this should be a comment to Kristiyan Varbanov's answer, i.e. that his solution did not work for me and will not work for collapsing toolbars in general. Unfortunately stackoverflow did not allow me to write comments, thus I tried to write an answer instead.